# How to get the context in the main class constructor?

Tags: java, android

I searched everywhere and I decided to write here. I'm trying to achieve a connection when my app starts. My problem is that I need to pass the context to the AsyncTask (or create ProgressDialog earlier in the constructor) - but I also need the context.

The most important thing: I can't move things from constructor to onCreate, cause it will make a new Client every time I open the app, go back etc.

The problem is here that when the constructor is fired, I don't have context yet.

Any ideas?

Already tried with this: `StartConnectionTask(this);` but this is the same thing.

Found this: http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/7/11/snippets-android-async-progress
implemented it and still the same. **Context is null.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Client client;
public Button loginButton;
public static String host = "192.168.1.2";
public static int tcp_port = 8888, udp_port = 8889;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);
}

public MainActivity(){
    client = new Client();
    client.start();
    Network.register(client);
    StartConnectionTask s = new StartConnectionTask(MainActivity.this);
    s.execute();
}

public class StartConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog conDialog;

    public StartConnectionTask(MainActivity activity) {
        conDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        conDialog.setTitle("Connecting with a server...");
        conDialog.setMessage("Connecting with " + host);
        conDialog.show();
        conDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
```

Comment: When your app is closed, constructor will be called again anyway, so the client will be recreated. Move it to onCreate. And if you want to use the same client throughout your app then extend Application class and put it there

Comment: Oh. Could you explain what do you mean by extending Application class? I'm stuck from two days, tried with Singletons, SharedPreferences, everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by OP, here's how you can override your Application class

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App mInstance;
    private Client mClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        // magic and stuff
        // put anything here and in anywhere in your app, activity
        // fragment, service, whatever you want
        // do App.getInstance().whatever()
        // like App.getInstance().getClient()

        mClient = new Client();
    }

    public static synchronized App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Client getClient() {
        return mClient;
    }

}
```

And specify this in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        ... >
```

Comment: So I should just create an App object in onCreate (in main class) like

App c = App.getInstance;

and then call c.mClient - is this correct sir?

Comment: `c.getClient()`, mClient is a private, but this is just a base for you, you can use this in any way you want. This is just to show you how to make something available in your entire app. And as I don't know what Client class is and what it does, I can't advice you any further

Answer (score 1):

you need to shift your code from `MainActivity()` to at the end of `onCreate`.

In android conventionally `onCreate` is the method where your activity starts as per activity lifecycle.
you can easily pass context from here by passing `this`

Answer (score 0):

Activity extend context class . when a activity is start it flow her life cycle so activities constructor no need you put this constructor code into on create method.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul Tiwari's answer will do. But in case, if you want to implement Application class to get the context throughout your aplication, try this.

public class App extends Application {

```
public static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Do your stuff here
    context = getApplicationContext();
    super.onCreate();
}  ...
```

And add this to your manifest

```
 <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.your.package.App ">
```